# Why does Spring MVC respond with a 404 and report "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [...] in DispatcherServlet"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm writing a Spring MVC application deployed on Tomcat. See the following [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
public class Application extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { };
    }
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { SpringServletConfig.class };
    }
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/*" };
    }
}
```

Where `SpringServletConfig` is

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.controllers")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringServletConfig {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver vr = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        vr.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsps/");
        vr.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return vr;
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a `@Controller` in the package `com.example.controllers`

```
@Controller
public class ExampleController {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String example() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

My application's context name is `Example`. When I send a request to

```
http://localhost:8080/Example/home
```

the application responds with an HTTP Status 404 and logs the following

```
WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI `[/Example/WEB-INF/jsps/index.jsp]` in `DispatcherServlet` with name 'dispatcher'
```

I have a JSP resource at `/WEB-INF/jsps/index.jsp` I expected Spring MVC to use my controller to handle the request and forward to the JSP, so why is it responding with a 404?

---

*This is meant to be a canonical post for questions about this warning message.*

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Your standard Spring MVC application will serve all requests through a [`DispatcherServlet`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet) that you've registered with your Servlet container.

The `DispatcherServlet` looks at its `ApplicationContext` and, if available, the `ApplicationContext` registered with a `ContextLoaderListener` for special beans it needs to setup its request serving logic. [These beans are described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet-special-bean-types).

Arguably the most important, beans of type [`HandlerMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping) map

> incoming requests to handlers and a list of pre- and post-processors
> (handler interceptors) based on some criteria the details of which
> vary by `HandlerMapping` implementation. The most popular implementation
> supports annotated controllers but other implementations exists as
> well.

The [javadoc of `HandlerMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html) further describes how implementations must behave.

The `DispatcherServlet` finds all beans of this type and registers them in some order (can be customized). While serving a request, the `DispatcherServlet` loops through these `HandlerMapping` objects and tests each of them with [`getHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html#getHandler-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-) to find one that can handle the incoming request, represented as the standard `HttpServletRequest`. As of 4.3.x, **if it doesn't find any**, it [logs the warning](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.3.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L1176) that you see

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI `[/some/path]` in `DispatcherServlet` with name SomeName

and [either](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html#setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound-boolean-) throws a [`NoHandlerFoundException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/NoHandlerFoundException.html) or immediately commits the response with a 404 Not Found status code.

## Why didn't the `DispatcherServlet` find a `HandlerMapping` that could handle my request?

The most common `HandlerMapping` implementation is [`RequestMappingHandlerMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html), which handles registering `@Controller` beans as handlers (really their `@RequestMapping` annotated methods). You can either declare a bean of this type yourself (with `@Bean` or `<bean>` or other mechanism) or you can use [the built-in options](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable). These are:

1. Annotate your `@Configuration` class with `@EnableWebMvc`.
2. Declare a `<mvc:annotation-driven />` member in your XML configuration.

As the link above describes, both of these will register a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean (and a bunch of other stuff). However, a `HandlerMapping` isn't very useful without a handler. `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` expects some `@Controller` beans so you need to declare those too, through `@Bean` methods in a Java configuration or `<bean>` declarations in an XML configuration or through component scanning of `@Controller` annotated classes in either. **Make sure these beans are present.**

If you're getting the warning message and a 404 and you've configured all of the above correctly, **then you're sending your request to the wrong URI**, one that isn't handled by a detected `@RequestMapping` annotated handler method.

The `spring-webmvc` library offers other built-in `HandlerMapping` implementations. For example, [`BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.html) maps

> from URLs to beans with names that start with a slash ("/")

and you can always write your own. Obviously, **you'll have to make sure the request you're sending matches at least one of the registered `HandlerMapping` object's handlers.**

If you don't implicitly or explicitly register any `HandlerMapping` beans (or if [`detectAllHandlerMappings`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html#setDetectAllHandlerAdapters-boolean-) is `true`), the `DispatcherServlet` registers some [defaults](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet-config). These are defined in [`DispatcherServlet.properties`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.3.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.properties) in the same package as the `DispatcherServlet` class. They are `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` and [`DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html) (which is similar to `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` but deprecated).

## Debugging

Spring MVC will log handlers registered through `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. For example, a `@Controller` like

```
@Controller
public class ExampleController {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/example", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "X-Custom")
    public String example() {
        return "example-view-name";
    }
}
```

will log the following at INFO level

```
Mapped "{[/example],methods=[GET],headers=[X-Custom]}" onto public java.lang.String com.spring.servlet.ExampleController.example()
```

This describes the mapping registered. When you see the warning that no handler was found, compare the URI in the message to the mapping listed here. All the restrictions specified in the [`@RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) must match for Spring MVC to select the handler.

Other `HandlerMapping` implementations log their own statements that should hint to their mappings and their corresponding handlers.

Similarly, enable Spring logging at DEBUG level to see which beans Spring registers. It should report which annotated classes it finds, which packages it scans, and which beans it initializes. If the ones you expected aren't present, then review your `ApplicationContext` configuration.

## Other common mistakes

A `DispatcherServlet` is just a typical Java EE [`Servlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html). You register it with your typical `<web.xml>` `<servlet-class>` and `<servlet-mapping>` declaration, or directly through [`ServletContext#addServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addServlet-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) in a [`WebApplicationInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html), or with whatever mechanism Spring boot uses. As such, you must rely on the *url mapping* logic specified in the [Servlet specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/), see Chapter 12. See also

- [How are Servlet url mappings in web.xml used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385596/how-are-servlet-url-mappings-in-web-xml-used)

With that in mind, a common mistake is to register the `DispatcherServlet` with a url mapping of `/*`, returning a view name from a `@RequestMapping` handler method, and expecting a JSP to be rendered. For example, consider a handler method like

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/example", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String example() {
    return "example-view-name";
}
```

with an [`InternalResourceViewResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html)

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver vr = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    vr.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsps/");
    vr.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return vr;
}
```

you might expect the request to be [forwarded](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward-javax.servlet.ServletRequest-javax.servlet.ServletResponse-) to a JSP resource at the path `/WEB-INF/jsps/example-view-name.jsp`. This won't happen. Instead, assuming a context name of `Example`, the `DisaptcherServlet` will report

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI `[/Example/WEB-INF/jsps/example-view-name.jsp]` in `DispatcherServlet` with name 'dispatcher'

Because the `DispatcherServlet` is mapped to `/*` and `/*` matches everything (except exact matches, which have higher priority), the `DispatcherServlet` would be chosen to handle the `forward` from the [`JstlView`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/JstlView.html) (returned by the `InternalResourceViewResolver`). **In almost every case, the `DispatcherServlet` will not be configured to handle such a request**.

Instead, in this simplistic case, you should register the `DispatcherServlet` to `/`, marking it as the default servlet. The default servlet is the last match for a request. This will allow your typical servlet container to chose an internal Servlet implementation, mapped to `*.jsp`, to handle the JSP resource (for example, Tomcat has [`JspServlet`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/servlet/JspServlet.html)), before trying with the default servlet.

That's what you're seeing in your example.

Comment: With @EnableWebMvc the dispatcherServlet it already registered to /. 

"you might expect the request to be forwarded to a JSP resource at the path /WEB-INF/jsps/example-view-name.jsp. This won't happen."

How do you make it work so that it forwards to a JSP resource at that path? That's basically the question asked.

Comment: @Tor On its own, `@EnableWebMvc` on a `@Configuration` annotated class does not do that. All it does is add a number of default Spring MVC handlers/adapters beans to the application context. Registering a `DispatcherServlet` to serve `/` is a completely separate process that's done in a number of ways that I describe in the **Other common mistakes** section. I answer _the question asked_ two paragraphs below what you quoted.

Answer (score 7):

I resolved my issue when in addition to described before:`

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver vr = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    vr.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsps/");
    vr.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return vr;
}
```

`added tomcat-embed-jasper:`

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

`
from: [JSP file not rendering in Spring Boot web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602010/jsp-file-not-rendering-in-spring-boot-web-application/22552855#22552855)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was following the [Interceptors Spring documentation for version 5.1.2](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-interceptors) (while using **Spring Boot v2.0.4.RELEASE**) and the `WebConfig` class had the annotation `@EnableWebMvc`, which seemed to be conflicting with something else in my application that was preventing my static assets from being resolved correctly (i.e. no CSS or JS files were being returned to the client).

After trying a lot of different things, I tried *removing* the `@EnableWebMvc` and it worked!

Edit: [Here's the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration) that says you should remove the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation

Apparently in my case at least, I'm already configuring my Spring application (although not by using `web.xml` or any other static file, it's definitely programmatically), so it was a conflict there.

Answer (score 2):

Try to amend your code with the following change on your config file. Java config is used instead of `application.properties`.
Do not forget to enable configuration in `configureDefaultServletHandling` method.

> `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class is deprecated, so we use `WebMvcConfigurer` interface.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/views/", ".jsp");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

I use gradle, your should have the following dependencies in `pom.xml`:

```groovy
dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.3.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: '9.0.35'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across another reason for the same error. This could also be due to the class files not generated for your controller.java file. As a result of which the  the dispatcher servlet mentioned in web.xml is unable to map it to the appropriate  method in the controller class.

```
@Controller
Class Controller{
@RequestMapping(value="/abc.html")//abc is the requesting page
public void method()
{.....}
}
```

In eclipse under Project->select clean ->Build Project.Do give a check if the class file has been generated for the controller file under builds in your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your server. Maybe delete the server and add the project once again and Run.

1. Stop the Tomcat server
2. Right click the server and select "Clean"
3. Right click server again and select "Clean Tomcat Work Directory"

Answer (score 0):

In my case using a tutorial for SpringBoot(2.7.3) RestController, startup failed with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider

I thought that Spring REST does not use WebMvc so I removed 'spring-boot-starter-web' and that resolved the startup problem.  However, POST requests failed with the '404 Not Found' issue described here and spent several hours experimenting with

- server.servlet.context-path
- @RestController vs @Controller etc, and
- SecurityConfig options

I finally resolved the 404 issue by

- restoring dependency 'spring-boot-starter-web'
- adding dependency
  javax.validation
  validation-api
  and after undoing my 101 debug hacks it worked.

Very painful because even with root logger at DEBUG, there were no server-side logs to help.

Answer (score -1):

For me, I found that my target classes were generated in a folder pattern not same as source. This is possibly in eclipse I add folders for containing my controllers and not add them as packages. So I ended up defining incorrect path in spring config.

My target class was generating classes under app and I was referring to com.happy.app

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.happy.app"></context:component-scan>
```

I added packages (not folders) for com.happy.app and moved the files from folders to packages in eclipse and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was playing around with import of secondary java config files into a main java config file.  While making secondary config files, I had changed the name of the main config class, but I had failed to update the name in web.xml.  So, every time that I had restarted my tomcat server, I was not seeing mapping handlers noted in the Eclipse IDE console, and when I tried to navigate to my home page I was seeing this error:

> Nov 1, 2019 11:00:01 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound
>   noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/webapp/home/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

The fix was to update the web.xml file so that the old name "WebConfig" would be instead "MainConfig", simply renaming it to reflect the latest name of the main java config file (where "MainConfig" is arbitrary and the words "Web" and "Main" used here are not a syntax requirement).  MainConfig was important, because it was the file that did the component scan for "WebController", my spring mvc controller class that handles my web requests.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={WebController.class})
```

web.xml had this:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        com.lionheart.fourthed.config.WebConfig
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

web.xml file now has:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        com.lionheart.fourthed.config.MainConfig
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

Now I am seeing the mapping in the console window:

> INFO: Mapped "{[/home/index],methods=[GET]}" onto public
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView
>   com.lionheart.fourthed.controller.WebController.gotoIndex()

And my web page is loading again.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had created Config.java (class) and also config.xml and mapping was done partially in both of them. And since config.java uses @Configuration annotation , it was considered priority. And was not considering config.xml.
If anyone gets in trouble like this , just delete config.java with annotation and try to keep config.xml , it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

### For me, the issue was hidden in the *web.xml* file.

Inside the servlet tag, you'll find:

```
<init-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/todo-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Make sure that in the `<param-value>` you have kept the correct location of the dispatcher servlet (aka Front Controller).

I had kept an incorrect location, hence I was able to view the homepage but all other pages were giving HTTP 404 error.

Answer (score -1):

In mapping URL if we are using **/*** (star after slash) we get this No mapping for Get message on console. Better to use only **/**. Instead of slash with start

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>employee</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score -2):

I had same problem as `**No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/some/path] in DispatcherServlet with name SomeName**`

After I analyzed for 2 to 4 days I found out the root cause. Class files was not generated after I run the project. I clicked the project tab.

> Project-->CloseProject-->OpenProject-->Clean-->Build project

Class files for source code have been generated. It solved my problem. To check whether class files have been generated or not, Please check the Build folder in your project folder.

Answer (score -3):

So the problem can be as simple as an additional space in the path of the project. Make sure that there is no space in the path which took me quite some time to solve.