# Where is databinding mapping stored for a controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In the following controller

```
@Controller
public class MyFormController {
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
    }
    // ...
}
```

The class does not inherit any other class or it doesn't have any WebDataBinder instance variable. How come then the custom editors are stored and where?

Comment: `it doesn't have any WebDataBinder instance variable` - but it has it as parameter

Comment: where is it stored then? how do link the controller and the parameter?

Comment: `where is it stored then?` - on stack?

Answer (score -1):

The Spring MVC infrastructure is complex. There are a lot of pieces that come together to invoke your `@Controller` handler method. I explain some of it in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41577235/438154).

In summary, Spring MVC scans your `@Controller` classes for `@RequestMapping` annotated methods. It creates mappings for these in a [`RequestMappingHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html) and uses a [`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html) to dispatch to them, ie. invoke your handler methods.

Before it invokes the method, it goes through a couple of housekeeping steps. You can see these in the source code, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.3.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java#L789). The short version is:

1. It wraps the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` in an adapter.
2. It creates factories producing `Model` and `WebDataBinder` instances (the latter come from your `@InitBinder` methods).
3. It creates a `ServletInvocableHandlerMethod` which encapsulates the invocation of your handler method with `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to generate arguments for your handler method and `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` to process the return value of your handler method.
4. It creates a `ModelAndViewContainer` which will potentially be used to later render a view as the HTTP response.
5. It prepares an async environment in case the request uses async components.

Then it invokes the method.

That `WebDataBinder` object you're curious about is stored and used in various places in the execution context described above.