# I tried looking for solutions for "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/DemoApp/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'servlet'"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, servlets

I cant understand where i am doing mistake i am not able to load any pages..
Also how to provide links to jsp pages in other jsp page. Like i did in my index page, will that work fine? because i am getting error (resource not found)
Please someone help.
This is my servlet file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <!-- <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" /> -->
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.demoapp.controller"></context:component-scan>
 </beans>
```

My controller..
      package com.demoapp.controller;

```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.List;


  import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
  import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
  import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

  import com.demoapp.entities.Student;
  import com.google.gson.Gson;
  import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
  import com.demoapp.service.StudentService;

  @Controller
  public class StudentController {

  StudentController() {

    System.out.println("Hello. Reached Controller");
}

@Autowired
StudentService studentService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String indexPage() {
    System.out.println("Hello. Index page Loading...");
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void addStudentToDB(@RequestBody String student) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println("student");
    Student studentObj = null;
    try {
        studentObj = mapper.readValue(student, Student.class);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    studentService.addStudent(studentObj);
    System.out.println("Student Added");

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/viewStudents", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String viewAllStudents() {
    List<Student> students = studentService.getStudents();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String jsonStudents = gson.toJson(students);
    System.out.println("Sending All Students");
    return jsonStudents;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void deleteStudentFromDB(@RequestBody String studentId) {
    System.out.println(studentId);
    int id = Integer.parseInt(studentId);
    studentService.deleteStudent(id);
    System.out.println("Student Deleted");

}
}
```

My Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>DemoApp</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>



<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list> -->

</web-app>
```

my spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.demoapp"></context:component-scan>

<bean id="transactionMangager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"></property>
    <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"></property>
</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

 <!-- To Create An Object Of CommonServiceImpl -->
<bean id="studentService" class="com.demoapp.serviceimpl.StudentServiceImpl"></bean>

<!--Down Autowire All The DAOs to the Respective DAOImpl classes -->
<bean id="studentDAO" class="com.demoapp.daoimpl.StudentDAOImpl">
</bean> 


</beans>
```

my index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
       uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
        <a href="<c:url value="AddStudent"/>">Add Student</a><br>
        <a href="<c:url value="ViewStudents"/>">View Students</a><br>
        <a href="<c:url value="DeleteStudent"/>">Delete Student</a><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this mapping in your web.xml for the SpringDispathcerServlet servlet:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41577235/4190848) you could find more info

Comment: still getting this error "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/DemoApp/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'servlet'"

Comment: Try url `/DemoApp/`instead of `/DemoApp/index`

Comment: i get this error in my console when i run the project in the server
Feb 06, 2017 2:42:46 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/DemoApp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'servlet'

Comment: Your view is `index.xml` or `index.jsp`?

Comment: i have changed it sorry @jlumietu