# noHandlerFound and showing 404 with no message in spring mvc

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-3.0

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>withDiffServletName</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

example-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
   <context:component-scan base-package = "com.app.simple" />
   <mvc:annotation-driven />
   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

controller

```
@Component
public class ConrrollController 
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public ModelAndView student() {
          return new ModelAndView("student", "command", "hi");
       }
}
```

index.jsp
/student

student.jsp
hi

hi all,
i am new in spring ,this is my 1 st program an getting an error 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/webroot/student] in DispatcherServlet with name 'sample'.
please provide me solution.an and encourage me .

i didnt understood 
[Why does Spring MVC respond with a 404 and report "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [...] in DispatcherServlet"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577234/why-does-spring-mvc-respond-with-a-404-and-report-no-mapping-found-for-http-req)

Answer (score 0):

No handler mapping is came because the controller not returning view .
So we need to change @controller not @components