# Spring: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [uri] in Dispatcher Servlet

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-web

This is a Spring MVC project where the view is redirected through servlet-dispatcher.xml. The dispatcher is unable to map to the given URI. Attached images contain the project structure that may also help to find the mistake. Following is the code:-

> Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


<display-name>Test Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

> dispatcher

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.practice.controller" />
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

> controller

```
package com.practice.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class Test {
String msg = "Hello Nigga";

@RequestMapping("/test")
public ModelAndView testController(
        @RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="Yooo") 
            String name){
    System.out.println("Test Controller");

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("testView");
    mv.addObject("msg",msg);
    mv.addObject("name", name);
    return mv;
}
```

}

[Console: Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcWLH.png)

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcWLH.png)

Thank You.

Comment: First check your "Deployment Assembly" . Does it have entry  "source = /webapp and Deploy path = /" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577234/why-does-spring-mvc-respond-with-a-404-and-report-no-mapping-found-for-http-req may help

Comment: Thank you for your instant reply @BhaveshVavadiya
I am already done checking all the sources and maven repositories

Comment: To be specific, i am working on spring verision 3.2.18
Thank you @ShibinaEC

Comment: You can also check that request you are sending is mapped with spring controller.
@ShibinaEC has posted very good link. It has covered possible senario for failer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @BhaveshVavadiya and ShibinaEC 
It was very helpful, the link by ShibinaEC explains everything in detail for Spring 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it does not work, because you realized root context only (which enabled via contextConfigLocation parameter). You should add context for spring servlet. You can see sample [here](https://github.com/raccoonberus/clientsvc/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) in rows 20-23. Context for servlet described [here](https://github.com/raccoonberus/clientsvc/blob/master/src/main/webapp/spring/appServlet-context.xml)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/spring/appServlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Just added the <init-param> content.
Thank You @GFB