# Spring MVC - no mapping found for HTTP request in DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am rewriting an API backend from Nodejs to Spring. This is my first Spring REST API backend application ever. I want to make it as simple as possible in order to avoid using `.xml(s)` by following [the Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-servlet)

This backend, since now, has only one controller and one service. The entire application it's not meant to serve any web pages, but REST API only.

I started up by writing a simple configuration based on the `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` and the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
public class WebInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{MvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.root.package")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   //I think I may not need anything inside here, right?
}
```

... and the controller as well...

```
@Controller("/locale")
public class LocaleController {

    @Autowired
    private LocaleService localeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/labels", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Label> getAll() {
        return localeService.getAll();
    }
}
```

It starts on Tomcat, I could debug it. Log shows `Mapped "{[/labels],methods=[GET]}"` and `Mapped URL path [/locale] onto handler '/locale'` but once I call that by postman, I see `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/locale/labels] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`.

Every research mainly headed me to [Why does Spring MVC respond with a 404 and report "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [...] in DispatcherServlet"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577234/why-does-spring-mvc-respond-with-a-404-and-report-no-mapping-found-for-http-req) -but- is a bit verbose and... almost every concept written is based on the Spring documentation that I was already following since I do not deep know Spring :)

I am sure that my issue has an easier solution. What I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a little error on your controller definition.
You wrote:

```
@Controller("/locale")
public class LocaleController {

    @Autowired
    private LocaleService localeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/labels", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Label> getAll() {
        return localeService.getAll();
    }
}
```

This means that the bean who spring will create will have the name "/locale"; if you want that the controller "answers" to the path /locale/labels you must write the Controller in this way:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/locale")
public class LocaleController {

    @Autowired
    private LocaleService localeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/labels", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Label> getAll() {
        return localeService.getAll();
    }
}
```

In this way you are telling spring that the controller `LocaleController` will answers to all the requests with prefix `/locale`; each method inside it will be called according to the calling path

Comment: Here you go! The latest distraction mistake on Java world... thank you also for the further explanation!